Unit testing mysql and nestjs
soy nuevo en esto. estoy intentando realizar el testing de una App (realizada con mysql, nestjs, typeOmr, etc) la cual tiene varios recursos cada uno con sus entidades y Dto correspondientes. al testiar user.service me arroja error en consola refiriendo:
RUNS  src/user/user.service.spec.ts
● UserService › should be defined
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserService (UserRepository, ?, CartService). Please make sure that the argument 

ProfileService at index [1] is available in the RootTestModule context.
Potential solutions:
- Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ProfileService is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
- If ProfileService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ProfileService */ ]
  })

  15 |
  16 |   beforeEach(async () => {
> 17 |     const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
     |                                   ^
  18 |       //agregado
  19 |       imports:[
  20 |         AppTestModule,//usa el modulo de prueba en lugar del original

y tambien:
FAIL  src/user/user.service.spec.ts
● Test suite failed to run
Cannot find module 'Test_Config/app.test.module' from 'user/user.service.spec.ts'

   7 | //import { UserModule } from './user.module';
   8 | import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
>  9 | import { AppTestModule } from 'Test_Config/app.test.module';
     | ^
  10 |
  11 | describe('UserService', () => {
  12 |   let service: UserService;

  at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (user/user.service.spec.ts:9:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.561 s
Ran all test suites matching /user.service/i.
para testiar cree una carpeta a la altura de src llamada Test_Config en la cual crree un App.Test.Module.ts en el que hice la coneccion a una base de datos "test"
